# MathOverflow site is forgotten

Tags: support, status-declined

At https://stackexchange.com/sites is forgotten http://mathoverflow.net site.

Please add it.

Answer (score 8):

[Mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net) is an SE 1.0 site. It has been a great success, and will therefore at some point be ported to SE 2.0 and be included in the Stack Exchange family that is listed on https://stackexchange.com/sites. Yet some work needs to be done - like integration of LaTex in SE 2.0 for certain sites, or better, adding a site specific plug-in system, and replacing all the meta questions back to a compatible site, as it seems.

There are other SE 1.0 sites out there that aren't listed, like [answers.onstartup.com](http://answers.onstartup.com) - quite successful - and [god.stackexchange.com](http://god.stackexchange.com) - needs resurrection, which is done in multiple proposals on Area 51 like [this one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1817/biblical-hermeneutics?referrer=sRPc-3Di_skN5QfMOt5KEg2).

So it is only a matter of time for the site to be ported and included.

Comment: note that there already are SE 2.0 sites that have working LaTeX integration, [math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) and [stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "will therefore at some point be ported to SE 2.0" I'm not sure this is a certainty - there are a few issues that have yet to be worked out.

Comment: yes it's unclear when/if mathoverflow will ever go to SE 2.0 -- you can check [their meta site](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/) to see what the latest news is. I honestly don't even know.

Comment: "god.stackexchange.com - needs resurrection" :)